# Парсинг по HTML без сторонних библиотек и переменных на JS

Tags: javascript

Нужна Ваша помощь, ребята)
Есть код HTML:

```
<div class="positive ">
            <div class="icon-container">
            </div>
            <div class="need">Text1<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="positive">
            <div class="icon-container">
            </div>
            <div class="need">Text2<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="negative">
            <div class="icon-container">
            </div>
            <div class="need">Text3<span class="separator">, </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Необходимо получить массив текста из тега , при условии что у родителя есть класс positive
нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки, а также вводить новые переменные.

Всю голову сламала и немогу понять как потом NodeList на выходе сделать масивом..

Результат должен выглядить [text1, text2, ...]

Comment: `Array.from(nodeList)` ?

Comment: Ну через интернет не видно как вы пытаетесь это сделать....почему-то))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбираейте

```
let array = [...nodeList];
```

или

```
let array = Array.from(nodeList);
```

или

```
let array = [].slice.call(nodeList);
```

---

Применение:

```js
let divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test'));
let textsArray = divs.map(item => item.textContent);


console.log(textsArray);
```

```html
<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
<div class="test">test4</div>
<div class="test">test5</div>
<div class="test">test6</div>
```

либо просто цикл

```js
let divNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
let textsArray = [];

divNodes.forEach(item => {
    textsArray.push(item.textContent)
});


console.log(textsArray);
```

```html
<div class="test">test1</div>
<div class="test">test2</div>
<div class="test">test3</div>
<div class="test">test4</div>
<div class="test">test5</div>
<div class="test">test6</div>
```

Comment: подозреваю проблема в том, что элементы массива это Node, а нужно текст получить :)

Comment: @Grundy возможно. просто прочитал до [text1, text2...]))

Comment: @Grundy добавил пример. хотя наверное тогда перевод в такой массив излишний

Comment: спасибо большое за примеры) 
а без введения переменных никак нельзя? 
какое то задание странное....)

Comment: @GP ну как минимум первый пример можно без переменной. Но думаю вы можете вложить одну функцию в другую и без моих примеров...правда?

Comment: я сделала уже без переменных - Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо :)

Comment: @GP Стоило бы тогда принять этот вариант решения, либо выложите в виде ответа ваш вариант и примите его